# Как отследить действия пользователя в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, webbrowser

Есть ли дополнение к браузеру или какой-то способ отследить все действия пользователя? Какие кнопки наживал, какие события происходили, чтобы в дальнейшем имитировать эти действия в коде?Что б как-бы написать макрос всех моих действий.

Comment: То, что вам нужно, называется Вебвизор. Данный функционал есть в Яндекс.Метрике (https://metrika.yandex.ru/) и в Гугл аналитикс (http://www.google.ru/analytics/)

Comment: Мне скорее нужно просто макрос моих собственных действий. Дело в том, что если в браузере клацаю по элементам- всё работает. А вот начинаю вроде то же самое воспризводить на jquery -не работает. Код писал не я- и сейчас надо дополнить и разобраться- что куда идёт- и вот в коде воспроизвести не могу. Яндекс вебвизор може записать макрос действий?

Comment: Вебвизор записывает поведение пользователя на сайте и вы можете посмотреть это как видео. Но я так понимаю вам нужно совсем не это, но не совсем понимаю что именно, особенно путает сравнение работоспобности "в браузере" и "на jquery", то есть "на jquery" вы клацаете не в браузере? Объясните суть того, что вам нужно, подробнее, с указанием конкретного кода.

Comment: На др форуме ещё посоветовали  trigger в javascript коде в дебагере. Суть в том, что я в урл хеше храню значения элементов и когда перезапускаешь-надо восстановить все элементы из урл. Основная масса восстанавливается, а некоторые выбираются "вживую-мышкой", а из кода не хотят- вот я и пытаюсь выяснить, в чём дело.

Comment: В принципе, я предполагал что вам нужно просто подебажить свой код, чтобы найти ошибку. В этом вам вполне поможет браузерный отладчик, где можно поставить breakpoint (а не trigger), а также добавить переменные для просмотра значений при активном breakpoint'е

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) возможно. Позволяет записывать и редактировать макросы, работает в виде плагина для Firefox.